# Error loading csv data into Hive table

Tags: r, hive, rjdbc

i have a csv file in hadoop and i have a Hive table ,now i want to laoad that csv file into this Hive table

i have used load LOAD DATA local 'path/to/csv/file' overwrite INTO TABLE tablename;

ended up with this error :

```
Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for ",  : 
Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for LOAD DATA local
'path/to/csv/file' overwrite INTO TABLE tablename 
(Error while processing statement: FAILED: 
ParseException line 1:16 missing INPATH at ''path/tp csv/file'' near '<EOF>'
)
```

Note: i am trying this using RJDBC connection in r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have developed a tool to generate hive scripts from a csv file. Following are few examples on how files are generated. 
Tool -- https://sourceforge.net/projects/csvtohive/?source=directory

1. Select a CSV file using Browse and set hadoop root directory ex: /user/bigdataproject/
2. Tool Generates Hadoop script with all csv files and following is a sample of 
   generated Hadoop script to insert csv into Hadoop

   ```
   #!/bin/bash -v

   hadoop fs -put ./AllstarFull.csv /user/bigdataproject/AllstarFull.csv
   hive -f ./AllstarFull.hive
   ```

   hadoop fs -put ./Appearances.csv /user/bigdataproject/Appearances.csv
   hive -f ./Appearances.hive

   hadoop fs -put ./AwardsManagers.csv /user/bigdataproject/AwardsManagers.csv
   hive -f ./AwardsManagers.hive
3. Sample of generated Hive scripts

   ```
   CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS lahman;

   USE lahman;

   CREATE TABLE AllstarFull (playerID string,yearID string,gameNum string,gameID string,teamID string,lgID string,GP string,startingPos string) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' stored as textfile;

   LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/bigdataproject/AllstarFull.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE AllstarFull;

   SELECT * FROM AllstarFull;
   ```

Thanks
Vijay

Answer (score 6):

I think the command to load CSV to Hive table is ( when CSV is in HDFS).

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/test/my.csv' INTO TABLE my_test;
```

Answer (score 6):

As your file is already present in the HDFS remove the keyword Local

LOAD DATA inpath 'path/to/csv/file' overwrite INTO TABLE tablename;