# load data into table hive

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I'm trying to Configure Hive to Work with JDBC and I used this exemple on eclipse :

```
public class HiveJdbcClient {
    private static String driverName = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
    /**
    * @param args
    * @throws SQLException
    **/
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/default", "", "");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String tableName = "testHiveDriverTable";
        stmt.executeQuery("drop table " + tableName);
        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("create table " + tableName + " (key int, value string)");

        // show tables
        String sql = "show tables '" + tableName + "'";
        System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
        res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        if (res.next()) {
            System.out.println(res.getString(1));
        }

        // describe table
        sql = "describe " + tableName;
        System.out.println("Running: " + sql);  
        res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while (res.next()) {
            System.out.println(res.getString(1) + "\t" + res.getString(2));
        }

        // load data into table
        // NOTE: filepath has to be local to the hive server
        // NOTE: /tmp/test_hive_server.txt is a ctrl-A separated file with two fields per line
        String filepath = "/tmp/test_hive_server.txt";
        sql = "load data local inpath '" + filepath + "' into table " + tableName;
        System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
        res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        // select * query
        sql = "select * from " + tableName;
        System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
        res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while (res.next()){
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(res.getInt(1)) + "\t" + res.getString(2));
        }
        // regular hive query
        sql = "select count(1) from " + tableName;
        System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
        res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while (res.next()){
            System.out.println(res.getString(1));
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to create the table on hive but when I try to load data into the table an  error appears . so my question is what should I put into "test_hive_server.txt" to make it work! Because I tried everything and each time I get the same error. 
Thanks!

the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Internal error processing execute
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:196)
    at com.palmyra.nosql.HiveJdbcClient.main(HiveJdbcClient.java:52)
```

Comment: Please post the error message also.

Comment: You may check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/31130602 for auto hive scripts generation tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by myself actually the :

```
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ';
```

determinate the format of the rows in the "file.txt" that we are going to load in the table and Hive’s default record and field delimiters list is :

```
\n

^A

^B

^C

press ^V^A could insert a ^A in Vim.
```

or you can just do:
 `create table  tableName (key int, value string)  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ';`

and the 'file.txt' should be like this:

```
value1 value2
value3 value4
```

in this example value1 and value3 represent the key
and value4 and value5 represent the value